# How to make scale transition of big images in Firefox more smooth? (like in Chrome)

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions, transition

I have a trouble, when I need to rotate big image(about 3000 - 5000px), that already scaled to 0.1 - in Firefox it goes not smooth. I think, it depends of Firefox render engine, because in Chrome, Opera and Safari everything is ok. 
How do you think,  is it possible to do the same in FF?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJp9v/1/) (you need to hover on circle in FF).

```
.item {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 3000px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    transition: all 5s linear;
}

.item:hover {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg) scale(0.1);
   transform: rotate(100deg) scale(0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for image-rendering css property :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Unfortunately default settings are the most optimized on Firefox, and as you said this task is handled by the browser itself, so there is pretty much nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks, I already checked this property, but it doesn't help. Quality became worse, but smoothing doesn't dissapear.

Comment: Sorry, this was your last resort, you will have to wait for a FF update :(